# changing the style of a tag that leads to a same page

Tags: html, css

how can i change the style of an `<a>` tag that links to the same page for example http://jsfiddle.net/6ffyubLy/

in this page both 'next' and '1' leads to the same page how can i change both of their styles on hover without giving them same class or id

```
<a href="jsfiddle.net">next</a>
<a href="jsfiddle.net">1</a>
<a href="#">2</a>

a:hover{
text-decoration:none;
```

}

Comment: `a[href="jsfiddle.net"]:hover{
    color:red;
}` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ffyubLy/2/)

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes i had tried it but didn't work http://jsfiddle.net/6ffyubLy/3/

Comment: on hover the `a` tag changes its `color` to `red` and other don't

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ffyubLy/4/) added background color for better view

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes i want both next and 1 to change color when either one of them is hovered

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ffyubLy/5/) use `~` sibling selector

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes that is a nice answer but what if the '2' and 'next' have the same link but you should make this an answer it was really great

Comment: Sibling selector will select only links _after_ the hover-link. For the desired kind of interaction, you might have to use JavaScript.

Comment: ya i know that so the solution would be use a use parent and target the children [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ffyubLy/6/)

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes problem is that the color becomes red even if it is hovered at 2 java is fine

Comment: yes @akshay use javascript

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
<a href="jsfiddle.net">next</a>
<a href="jsfiddle.net">1</a>
<a href="#">2</a>

a:hover{
   text-decoration:none;
}

a[href="jsfiddle.net"]:hover {
   color: red;
}
```

every page with a href that is jsfiddle will be red when you hover over the `<a>`

Comment: what i need is that if you hover over one of the link that leads to the page 'jsfiddle' all the link that leads to 'jsfiddle' must change color